# Removing Images from a WordPress Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to remove the images from a WordPress post to give me more control of how I could layout the design for the front page of a website. After doing some messing around and failing, I finally found a great post which had an amazing little piece of code that solved my problem.

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $post->post_content);
echo $postOutput;
?>
```

But some time i have link above images like:

```
<a href="#"><img src="PATH_IMAGES"></a>
```

So, How can remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Change above code by following code which remove link if exist into your content.

```
$content = get_the_content();
$postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $post->post_content);
$postContent = preg_replace("/<a[^>]+\>/i", "", $postOutput);
echo $postContent;
```

Comment: nice , its delete `<img>` and `<a>` but show me end of href `</a>` i need delete this `</a>`

Comment: It will delete both..<a> and </a>

Comment: i try but delete only `<a>`